# Is it possible to embed the list function in a foreach statement in PHP?

Tags: php, list, foreach, shortcut

I've thought about this problem before but never got anywhere on it. I think I've done it with Python but never PHP.

Define a basic php array:

```
$arr = array (array(1,2,3), array(4,5,6), array(7,8,9));
```

Then run this snippet:

```
foreach ($arr as $row)
{
    list($a, $b, $c) = $row;
    echo "$a, $b, $c <br>";
}
```

This is so common, I must have done it a million times during my php career...but it seems a bit wasteful. $row is a temp variable and is never really used and the list()= line seems like it should be able to be put into the foreach bracket

Something like this (of course, this doesn't work):

```
foreach ($arr as list($a, $b, $c) = $row)
{
    echo "$a, $b, $c <br>";
}
```

Neither does:

```
foreach ($arr as list($a, $b, $c))
{
    echo "$a, $b, $c <br>";
}
```

Has anyone come up with a cool shortcut for this?
Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with `echo $row[0], $row[1], $row[2], '<br>';`?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with referencing explicitly...but in a big block of code I like to have named variables.

Comment: In better form, I should have named my array "$arr" instead of $a...my bad for that....oh, I can edit, nice. New to SO.

Comment: I'm going to venture a guess that `$row`'s being your sole "wasted" variable is pretty well optimized altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, kind of. Use this:

```
while( list( $key, list( $a, $b, $c ) ) = each( $array ) ) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

Note the use of `list` twice - `each` returns the key-value pair, and the value is also an array so we use `list` again.

You can also use `list( , list( $a, $b, $c ) )`, leaving out `$key` if you want. But I think that's kind of ugly syntax. ;)

Comment: You saved a variable, to add another one. You made the code unreadable. This kind of advice just scares me. :)
Nonetheless, you are giving to the OP what s/he is asking for.

Comment: @Shef Yup. Personally, I'd just access them as arrays - `$value['a']`. But that's what the OP wanted...

Comment: @landons Might be creative; not my creation though. Based on the PHP `foreach` documentation. ;)

Comment: Man, only takes minutes! I would give this a thumbs up because it accomplishes the task but I don't think I'd use it in my day-to-day programming. Was, possibly naively, hoping for something a bit more compact and readable (sort of pythonic). Not to start a debate but I do wish some of Python's were present in PHP...and this is coming from a dyed in the wool PHP guy. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$array = array( array(1, 2, 3), array(4, 5, 6), array(7, 8, 9) );
for($next = current($array), list($a, $b, $c) = $next;
    // ^ current array           ^ current list
    $next;
    // ^ check if array
    $next = next($array), list($a, $b, $c) = $next)
    // ^ next array         ^ next array's list
{
    echo "$a, $b, $c <br>".PHP_EOL;
}
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/cuYl6iaa

Output:

```
1, 2, 3 <br>
4, 5, 6 <br>
7, 8, 9 <br>
```

Answer (score 1):

While this will not embed list into foreach, another approach you can find is to use for instead of foreach, and that way, bypassing the temporal variable this way:

```
$a = array (array(1,2,3), array(4,5,6), array(7,8,9));
$count=(int)count($a);
for ($i=(int)0; $i<count; $i++) {
    list($a, $b, $c)=$a[$i];
    echo "$a, $b, $c<br />";
}
```

With this I've added 2 variables more, but they contain only integer, which definitelly reduces memory usage by removing the temporal variable which will contain an array.

Comment: You have not only added 2 variables, but you have changed the code altogether to a different solution. Furthermore what is the logic in `$i=(int)0`?

Comment: Just to force int casts, I do code that way sometimes when a certain type is needed. It do not hurt. Yes I changed solution but at least I gave another aproach.